# Replacing existing ios app with a PhoneGap version

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I've been getting mixed reviews recently on one of my apps so I've been working on a HTML5 phonegap replacement.

Do I just have to match the bundle ID up with the existing app?

I have tried to create a new app using the following command `phonegap create "CSCS Revision" --id "<my bundle ID>" --name "<my app name>"`. However, I have a problem, `<my bundle ID>` contains a hyphen, and phonegap tells me that it's an invalid character, is there a way to override this?

The next thing I tried was creating the app and then changing the bundle ID. This seemed to work OK, but when I copied over the contents of my `www` directory from the other app it seems that some of the javascript files aren't included properly in the HTML.

I have one file called `data.js` that just has a big array in it, but it seems that the array can't be accessed in the newly created app despite it working in the other app which is a direct copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I was being a little slow on the uptake.

The way to get this submitted to Apple is to give it an id that is valid by phonegap in the command `phonegap create "CSCS Revision" --id "<my bundle ID>" --name "<my app name>"`

Add your javascript and html to the `www` directory, however unlike myself don't make a change before doing the copy that makes the javascript crash.

Run the command `phonegap build ios`. Then change the Bundle ID in the project settings. At this point you can then archive the project and submit it to the App Store.

One problem I had was missing icons. I like to use [this website](http://makeappicon.com/) to make all of my icons of the required sizes. I then copied the icon portion of the `config.xml` file from [this app](https://github.com/BelinChung/HiApp) into my `config.xml` and reran `phonegap build ios` (if you do this you'll have to change the bundle ID again in xcode before submitting to the store).